# How do I make this CSS pattern display behind all other elements?

Tags: html, css

From http://enjoycss.com/  I used a pattern to make a background grid such as this one

```
    .gradient-pattern {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 8.5in;
  height: 11in;
  border: none;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(209,209,209,1) 0, #FFFFFF 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(209,209,209,1) 0, #FFFFFF 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(209,209,209,1) 0, rgba(255,255,255,0.298039) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(209,209,209,1) 0, rgba(255,255,255,0.298039) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), rgba(255,255,255,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(209,209,209,1) 0, #FFFFFF 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(209,209,209,1) 0, #FFFFFF 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(209,209,209,1) 0, rgba(255,255,255,0.298039) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(209,209,209,1) 0, rgba(255,255,255,0.298039) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), rgba(255,255,255,1);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(209,209,209,1) 0, #FFFFFF 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(209,209,209,1) 0, #FFFFFF 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(209,209,209,1) 0, rgba(255,255,255,0.298039) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(209,209,209,1) 0, rgba(255,255,255,0.298039) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), rgba(255,255,255,1);
  background-position: -2px -2px, -2px -2px, -1px -1px, -1px -1px;
  -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-background-size: 100px 100px, 100px 100px, 20px 20px, 20px 20px;
  background-size: 100px 100px, 100px 100px, 20px 20px, 20px 20px;
    }
```

However when I place elements on the page, the pattern obscures the elements (all elements such as text, buttons etc)

How can I make this pattern a true background?

I set it on a div like this, and place the elements inside the div.

```
<div class="gradient-pattern"></div>
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by *pattern obscures the elements*. You have set the pattern as a background and so it shouldn't be affecting any content that is inside. Can you show a demo of what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "true background"?  Applying a background to the `<body>` would be a normal way of doing it.

Comment: I dont see they obscures. What navigator are you using? Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/dasqwg0b/

Comment: @Del sorry pasted the wrong pattern, see modification above to the css

Comment: Still working, what is the problem, you dont see the white text with this background? https://jsfiddle.net/dasqwg0b/1/

Comment: Also, the background have a color property, that can be inherit by his childrens. If you want to change that, just apply the color property you want to all of them

Comment: @Del actually in your first jsfiddle, if you replace the css with my updated one the text appears white and is no longer visible

Comment: Of course, white text in white background is not visible, set a color property to your text if you want a white background

Comment: @Del Ok thanks, my text had no style applied, so I guess it must have inherited the style from the parent div as you said.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, assign the relevant settings to the `body` tag:

```
body {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #FFFFFF 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px), -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #FFFFFF 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px), -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.298039) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px), -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.298039) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px), rgb(34, 102, 153);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, #FFFFFF 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px), -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #FFFFFF 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px), -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.298039) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px), -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.298039) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px), rgb(34, 102, 153);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #FFFFFF 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px), linear-gradient(90deg, #FFFFFF 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px), linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.298039) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px), linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.298039) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px), rgb(34, 102, 153);
  background-position: -2px -2px, -2px -2px, -1px -1px, -1px -1px;
  -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-background-size: 100px 100px, 100px 100px, 20px 20px, 20px 20px;
  background-size: 100px 100px, 100px 100px, 20px 20px, 20px 20px;
}
```

Comment: i only want the background to display inside my div, not the whole document body

Comment: well, then make that an own class (but witout all the other stuff you had in there originally) and assign that class to your DIV. IT,s quite a dark background pattern, so it won't really work well behind black text, though. But you can place other DIVs (boxes with text) on top of it, to which you assign a white background, for example, then you'll have white boxes with black text over that dark-blue background pattern.